Does "volume" equal "the amount of"?
According to the OALD, volume is the amount of something. However, I heard people talking about sales volume a lot. Sales is a plural noun, and it refers to the number of items sold, so  why does it go with volume?

Downvote for relying on a single dictionary, and a learner's dictionary at that. They oversimplify. Your command of the language is good enough for you to have graduated to several real dictionaries.

“Volume.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/volume. Accessed 24 Apr. 2024.

Yeah I should have thought about looking it up in other dictionaries as well. Do you mean to say volume in "sales volume" is in sense 3a(2) in M-W? Does that mean "volume" can only be used with countable nouns when the quantity is large?

“Quantity.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quantity. Accessed 24 Apr. 2024.

Volume - 3a (2): a considerable quantity

Not sure what you intend by bolding "considerable".  “Considerable.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/considerable. Accessed 24 Apr. 2024.

Hmm. I think I should ask you first if you were referring to entry 3a (2) of the word "volume" in M-W dictionary. Because that's what I thought you meant at first when you said I should have used more than one dictionary

With a phrase like sales volume the crudest definition  [here 3a(2)] could suffice, though it's certainly possible for people to perceive the phrase in a figurative sense, a rate, as there's  a measurement taken over a span of time (week, month, quarter, year, whatever); see M-W #2.    How are "sales" a "three-dimensional object" [or substance]?  Only in a figurative sense. Compare "cash flow" and "currency".  Money talk is often figurative.

Thank you. I'll try making up some phrases using this sense of the word. How about: "production volume" and "registered vehicle volume", which I mean to refer to the number of registered vehicles in a country in a certain year? I think I've heard of "vehicle volume" before. But I'm not sure if it can mean that.

I've heard "The volume of vehicles on the road will increase as we approach the holiday" so "vehicle volume" is not far-fetched especially on a chart.  But "registered vehicle volume" seems unlikely, though it's not ungrammatical.  production volume is well-established, like sales volume.

Why is "the volume of vehicles registered in 2010 increased" unlikely? Is it because there's no imaginary flow of vehicles, which can be imagined with the help of the phrase "on the road" in your example?

That's not what I wrote. What I wrote was "registered vehicle volume seems unlikely".

"The volume of vehicles on the road" relates to physical space, and possibly to vehicles getting larger, so it makes some sense to use "volume". It's less common to use volume with something more abstract like the number of things on a list or register. "Volume of vehicle registrations" actually means the number of new vehicles, so it is something physical, but "volume of registered sales" works less well. But even then, it's understandable. Note that questions of usage are seldom right v. wrong, they're common v. rare/awkward/unidiomatic.

@TimR Aren't "the volume of vehicles registered" and "the registered vehicle volume" the same thing? Could you define what each phrase means, of course without using the word "volume"?

They are not same grammatically. We are talking about language here not about the underlying concept.

From the point of view of usage, not grammar, when the noun is not understood to be a mass, like "porridge", we'd probably be more likely to use "number" not "volume".  "The number of vehicles on the road will triple on the national holiday" vs "Traffic volume will triple on the national holiday"; for that reason,  "traffic volume" is more likely than "vehicle volume".  Some nouns, like "sales", can be understood in either way, as discrete transactions or as an accumulated dollar (euro, whatever) value over a given time period. Sales volume presents it as a accumulation.

I got it now. Thanks a lot for your patience.

Volumes are often rates, think of the amount of water flowing through a pipe in a given time, that is a volume.
So is the rate of items sold in some amount of time, and that is what is meant by "sales volume" (whether over a day, a week month or otherwise). It might be expressed in currency rather than item count, but that is just a matter of how the business chooses to look at the data.
